# I can not bend the grille

Tags: modeling

I am modeling a front car bumper grille and I faced a problem: the grille doesn't bend all. I use a Subdivision Surface modifier to model my grille and this happens after I use Knife Project to make the bend line of my grille. Help me, please. Here is an image: [image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: what do you mean, how is it supposed to bend, what are you trying to do, how does the real grille look like?

Comment: I create my car that doesn't exist in the real world, that's why there are no images. The next image, maybe,  is funny but I hope you'll understand what I want to do: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcY2s.jpg

Comment: This happens after I use Knife Project to make the bend line of my grille.

Comment: why don't you use a curve modifier to deform the grille?  just add a curve, adjust the handles so that they are at the top and bottom of the grill, add the modifier, and adjust the curves till you get the curve you want.